# graph of the size of a complex function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, presentations-of-groups

Hi
Here there are two graphs for two functions from $R^2\mapsto R$.

Is there similar graph for the absolute value of a complex variable function $f:C\mapsto C$ that has the same point (like saddle point or transition). I know some functions that have the point $(x,y,|f(x+iy)|)$ on that such that in one direction it is maximum, and in the other direction it is minimum.

My question here is that: is there any such point such that in one direction it is maximum (or minimum) but in the other direction it is not maximum nor minimum (similar to $(0,0)$ in $y=x^3$ in the real case).

Thanks

[link text](http://postimage.org/image/v2ig8ycx7)

[link text](http://postimage.org/image/57zgroy4t)

Comment: Without further restrictions on your function $f$ (analytic? anti-analytic?) the answer is that a function $C \to R$ is exactly the same as a function $R^2\to R$.

Comment: $f$ is analytic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any nonconstant analytic function $f$, if $f'(p) = 0$ but $f(p)$ and $f''(p)$ are nonzero, then the graph of $|f(z)|$ will have a saddle point at $p$.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Yes, it is. but I was meaning that in one direction similar to $x^2$ and in the other direction similar to $x^3$. For example: $f(z)=cos(z)$ in $z=0$ has that condition, $|f|$ in one direction is like $x^2$ and in the other is like $(−x^2)$

Comment: Is it possible $f'(z)\neq0$ and $f(z)\neq0$, but $z$ is saddle point of the above type.

Comment: If $f'(p) \ne 0$, it's not a saddle point.  The definition of a saddle point requires a stationary point.